# Initialize boolean value "no such instance field"

Tags: android, android-context

I get an error in debugging and I can't set this boolean value. I attached a screenshot of the error.

[image]

I call DeviceUpdateManager in my mainActivity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DeviceUpdateManager.OnDataCOM {
    DeviceUpdateManager deviceUpdateManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.deviceUpdateManager = new    DeviceUpdateManager(this.serverCOM,this.getApplicationContext(),this);
    }
etc...
}
```

I cannot find the error... Is it related to the passing Context in another class?

**EDIT:SOLVED**
I reboot the PC and restarted Android Studio and everything worked great.

Comment: make your boolean variable public.

Comment: I just tried it. It doesn't work. Same error

Comment: Is it a new attribut in this class? Are you running the correct version of the application? Delete the current application and try again.

Comment: I think you are not initialized boolean value of "can" in InitializeVariables() method.Please check once

Comment: @Kakumanusivakrishna What do you mean of initialized? I put in  InitializeVariables() "this.can=true;"

Answer (score 2):

It happens when you changed variable name in code and running application with older name in code.

Answer (score 1):

Remove below snippet from Project/build.gradle file.

```
 minifyEnabled true
```

Please have a look at this link for more info.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45281798/5870824