# Android - No such instance field

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason I'm getting that error

> Android - No such instance field:databaseref

I can't find where I'm wrong. I just want to get ref to my database to get all the users.

The code:

```
public class FirebaseMethodsHelper {
    private FirebaseDatabase databaseRef;
    private ArrayList<User> usersList;


    public List<User> getAllUsersFromDB(FirebaseUser currentUser){
        databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        usersList = null;
        if(currentUser != null) {
            databaseRef.getReference(Params.USERS).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        usersList.add(snapshot.getValue(User.class));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            return usersList;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In some cases, this has been resolved by rebuilding the app or restarting Android Studio.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646999/no-such-instance-field

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 databaseRef.getReference(Params.USERS).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
```

to this:

```
 databaseRef.getReference().child(Params.USERS).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
```

Comment: How does this make a difference? As far as I can see the two snippets will  attach a listener to the same reference.